# CopyAgent (Copy Cloud Storage) won't autostart at system startup (Linux/Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, autostart

CopyAgent (the client from [Copy Cloud Storage](https://www1.copy.com/home/)) refuses to autostart at system startup. I use Xubuntu 13.04, and even though CopyAgent .desktop file is in the autostart folder, it simply won't autostart at the beginning of every session. It has to be started manually.

These are the contents of the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
Exec=/home/johnny/copy (install)/x86/CopyAgent
Icon=/home/johnny/.icons/copy-root_folder.png
Name=CopyAgent
Comment=Sync files across computers, mobile devices, and to the web
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Any ideas? I'm really puzzled with this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it.

In kubuntu/kde, go to directory `~/.kde4/Autostart` (or more likely it is `~/.kde/Autostart`) and create a symlink from `/path/to/CopyAgent` to `~/.kde/Autostart/CopyAgent`

I do not know about Xubuntu, but regardless of whatever the desktop environment, this can be achieved too by creating a symlink from `/path/to/CopyAgent` to `/etc/init.d/`

This what works for me:

> sudo ln -s ~/bin/copy/CopyAgent /etc/init.d/CopyAgent

(you would need to **modify** this according to where you have your CopyAgent is installed)

After a reboot, CopyAgent is running.

Another way to do this is by editing /etc/rc.d/boot.local and put a `/path/to/CopyAgent` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some symbolic link in your Copy folder? Mine was closing suddely and wasn't autostarting. Since I removed the symbolic links it started to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, the .desktop file needs to be placed in the `~/.config/autostart` directory.  If that directory doesn't exist, simply create it.